# How to copy mailItem.Body with line breaks to a website Textarea?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using `objItem.Body` to fill in a website text area.

With HTML emails it adds spaces for line breaks or something, how do I fix that? Here is an [example e-mail.](http://nerd-alert.info/images/hesk/001.png)

Using `ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = objItem.Body` you can see that two extra spaces/returns are added. It also adds `HYPERLINK="mailto:xxxxx"`.

Converting to plain text with something like:

```
objitem.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain 
objItem.Body = Replace(objItem.Body, " " & vbCrLf, vbCr)
```

retains the extra spacings and ruins the original email (I want to keep screenshots etc).

How can I get the `mailItem.Body` to transfer correctly?

Comment: I hope this makes sense..  where there might be one space in between two lines, there are 3... doesn't do this if the user does Shift+enter in the email, or anything auto returned.

Comment: Hi User, welcome to SO.  Can you give us a specific example?

Comment: Can you replace any instances of two line breaks with a single break?

Comment: htmlBody inputs the html code of the email into the textarea... let me post some screenshots because stackoverflow will mess with the lin spacings too lol....

Comment: alright all, as requested I have added more details.. (usually gets thrown out when i add this much info =()

Comment: This is an untested guess, but what if you removed the first character from ObjItem.Body?

Comment: what do you mean by this? bjItem.Body? ObjItem = current selected message for me...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing left is removing Hyperlinks! IE HYPERLINg "mailto:email"email and HYPERLINK"website"website

This is how to get the objitem.body to do correct spacings on html emails..

`ie.document.getElementById("message").Value = Replace(objItem.Body, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)`